# В чем разница ToolBar и SupportActionBar?

Tags: android

В чем разница ToolBar и SupportActionBar?

Я знаю что ToolBar это ActionBar с возможностью добавления своего кастомного ActionBara.

Но зачем это все если можно использовать getSupportActionBar и добавить туда setContentView и туда добавить такой же кастомный View?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1.Слово support - поддержка. SupportActionBar ошибочное понимание.

2.Из оф. источника.

> getSupportActionBar() Support library version of getActionBar().

Суть такая, что если вы используете support lib то getSupportActionBar() == toolbar. Тк именно он поддерживается данной библиотекой. Android настоятельно рекомендует использовать именно getSupportActionBar() при получении ActionBar, так в противном случае сработает getActionBar() и вы будете работать с ним. Получается, что getSupportActionBar() будет получать всегда актуальную версию ActionBar.

3.Toolbar != ActionBar, точней будет сказать он пришел на полную замену.

Подытожу: Используем Toolbar, получаем его методом getSupportActionBar()

Comment: Но на вопрос то не ответили вы. Зачем мне ToolBar если есть getSupportActionBar().setContentView. Куда меньше кода и тоже самое ведь делает....

Answer (score 6):

`ActionBar`, по сути, если брать при прочих равных, одна из разновидностей `Toolbar`. Отображает название, кнопки, для поиска/навигации/меню.

`Toolbar` включает намного больше в себя, чем `ActionBar`. Да, можно его использовать в качестве `ActionBar`, но можно настроить его поведение и взаимодействие с ним, реакцию на различные события, анимировать, добавить туда что угодно, легко управлять содержимым в `xml`.

`Toolbar` независим от оформления, т.е., как Вы добавляете `Button` или любой другой виджет, так Вы можете добавить и `ToolBar`, т.е. можно добавить сразу несолько `ToolBar`ов.

`ActionBar` не обязательно заменять на `Toolbar`, если он просто для отображения названия и менюшки, но если нужен какой-то дополнительный функционал, которого у `ActionBar` нет, то вот тут и вспомните про `Toolbar`.